# Вывод часов и минут из секунд

Tags: php, время

Есть число "4800" в минутах, как из него получить вывод "3 дня 3 часа 29 секунд" ?

Использую:

```
date('G:i:s', $user['playtime'])
```

Получаю вывод - 3:00:00

Как правильно вывести?

Comment: В 1 минуте 60 секунд.

Comment: Проще всего - через остаток от деления. Делим на 60, потом на 24. Если не хотим математику - смотрите ф-ции работы с временем - Прийдется перевести в секунды или милисекунды умножением, и создать обьект дата-время - тогда ваша строка сработает верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, функцию написал - перевод минут в дни часы и минуты. Секунды вывести не получится, потому что у вас точность минутная. Секунд, фактически, не существует.

```
function getDayHourMinut($minutes){

  $hours=floor($minutes/60);
  $minutes%=60;

  $day=floor($hours/24);
  $hours%=24;

  echo 'day='.$day.' hours='.$hours.' minutes='.$minutes;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в часах я получаю вывод 80.1223332223 , как можно округлить и выводить только 80? Без десятичных чтобы

Comment: @Андрей Ужегов перед нужнвм числом поставить (int). Пример `$val=(int) 21.987; print $val; //будет 21`